# BOOL CImageList::Replace( int nImage, CBitmap* pbmImage, CBitmap* pbmMask )

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I have an imagelist.

For some operations I am extracting toolbar images and replacing the image in the imagelist  using

[`BOOL CImageList::Replace( int nImage, CBitmap* pbmImage, CBitmap* pbmMask );`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xc4z2c7.aspx#cimagelist__replace)

I need to apply mask color RGB(255,0,255) while replacing.

```
ICONINFO iconinfo;
GetIconInfo(hIcon, &iconinfo);
HBITMAP hBitmap = iconinfo.hbmColor;
m_imgListSingle.Replace(0,CBitmap::FromHandle(hBitmap),???)
```

I dont know what I need to pass for third argument for CImageList Replace function.

Comment: Apparently you already have an icon. Icons come with a mask bitmap already. Why do you have to create your own, presumably different mask bitmap based on a key color?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use the Replace function with a mask color directly.

You may succeed in using the following sequence:

- Use the `CImageList::Add` method with the appropriate mask color
- Use `CImageList::GetImageInfo` to extract the bitmaps that got created by the Add command
- Use the `CImageList::Replace` method with the extracted bitmaps
- use the `CImageList::Delete` method to delete the newly created image.
- Dont't forget to free the bitmaps you retrieved by `CImageList::GetImageInfo`